# Equality comparer `FindIndex` vs `IndexOf`

Tags: c#

I have this line of code:

```
int MyIndex = MyListOfCustomObjects.IndexOf(CandidateObject); 
// assume CandidateObject exists in the list
```

Now I know that [List.FindIndex Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9.aspx):

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by a
>   specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first
>   occurrence within the List or a portion of it.

I was wondering, do all objects of a certain class have the same size?

If yes, and since that there is no *specified predicate* using the `IndexOf`,  then what *conditions* should be *matched* in order for `CandidateObject` to be found within `MyListOfCustomObjects`?

Also, what is meant by "*.. or a portion of it.*"?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Your title mentions "Equality comparer", but not the body of the question. Likewise, you ask about FindIndex, but your example code uses IndexOf. Those are two different methods...

Comment: You should be asking one question per question, not several.

Comment: @Mike I am asking about "equality comparer" of `IndexOf`. How does my "example code" know which object is the match?

Comment: @Servy, maybe I should fix that. Thanks

Comment: @FirstStep, then I suggest reading [the documentation of IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than that of FindIndex....

Comment: @Mike I did, and you should understand my question. Thanks

Comment: @FirstStep If you're asking about "equality comparer", shouldn't your question actually contain that phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then what conditions should be matched in order for `CandidateObject` to be found within `MyListOfCustomObjects`?

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) indirectly answers that:

> This method determines equality using the default equality comparer [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) for `T`, the type of values in the list.

If you follow the link for [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx), you'll find that it calls either the generic `Equals(T)` method defined for the class (if one exists), or a non-generic `Equals(object)` overload.  If `T` does not implement/override either method, then *reference* equality is used by default, since that's how `object.Equals(object)` is defined.

Scott has answered your question about "..or a portion of it." perfectly, and I am not certain what you mean by "the same size" or what it has to do with equality.  There's no guarantee that two *objects* of the same class have the same memory footprint, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

All items will only take up 1 index slot, so you could think of them as "having the same size".

`IndexOf` has no predicate you can define, but it does still follow one. You can think of `IndexOf` as implemented as

```
public int IndexOf(T item)
{
    return this.FindIndex(x => item.Equals(x));
}
public int IndexOf(T item, int startIndex)
{
    return this.FindIndex(startIndex, x => item.Equals(x));
}
public int IndexOf(T item, int startIndex,int count)
{
    return this.FindIndex(startIndex, count, x => item.Equals(x));
}
```

The "or a portion of it" part is for when you are using the overloads that take in `startIndex`, this allows you to start searching partway into the list, starting at the provided index instead of starting at 0. For example if you wanted to find the 2nd item you would find the index of the first then call find again on the result + 1 to find the 2nd index.